# How to pass the index into map() function

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following code

```
x=0;y=0;mtrx=[[1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,1,1,1],[0,0,1,0,1,0],[1,1,0,0,1,0],[1,0,1,1,0,0],[1,0,0,0,0,1]];

def colmnFun(colmn):
    column = colmn*5
    return column

def rowFun(row):
    row=list(map(colmnFun,row))
    return row

result=list(map(rowFun,mtrx))
print(result)
```

In this case the result will be

```
[[5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 5, 0, 5, 5, 5], [0, 0, 5, 0, 5, 0], [5, 5, 0, 0, 5, 0], [5, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0], [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5]]
```

I need to make specific math in column function based on the mtrx index, how can i pass the index to the function?

For example:

```
if x=1:
   column = (colmn+2)*5
else if y=3:
   column = colmn+1
```

Comment: ```x,y,mtrx=0,0,[[1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,1,1,1],[0,0,1,0,1,0],[1,1,0,0,1,0],[1,0,1,1,0,0],[1,0,0,0,0,1]]```, - this is correct.

Comment: You might consider numpy for matrix manipulations.

Comment: What do you want to achieve, exactly?

Comment: Your function name and parameter both are same `colmn(colmn)` and `row(row)`, you'll ultimately get error.

Comment: i need to pass the position of the element to the function to make some math based on the array position and it's value.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the desired output; see the [mcve] page for help. While you are at it, please rename the parameters of your functions so that they are not the same as the function name – while this is not an error, it is highly confusing.

Comment: MisterMiyagi, you are correct i edit it.

Comment: with `map` first you would have to create list with pairs `(row, index)`. Better use normal `for`-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Map do take iterables as argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) so you could use enumerate to pack the input to a tuple. To send it a second time you have to append the row index to the current column function using [partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools)

```
from functools import partial

mtrx = [[1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,1,1,1],[0,0,1,0,1,0],[1,1,0,0,1,0],[1,0,1,1,0,0],[1,0,0,0,0,1]]


def colmnFun(row_idx, column_data):
    print(row_idx)
    print(column_data)
    col_idx, value = column_data
    if col_idx == 1:
       return (value + 2) * 5
    if row_idx == 3: 
        return value + 1
    return value

def rowFun(row_data):
    row_idx, row = row_data
    print(row)
    row = list(map(partial(colmnFun, row_idx), enumerate(row)))
    return row

result=list(map(rowFun, enumerate(mtrx)))
print(result)
```

With the result:

```
[[1, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 15, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 10, 1, 0, 1, 0], [2, 15, 1, 1, 2, 1], [1, 10, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 10, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

But... I think it would be much easier to use [numpy](https://numpy.org/) here or simple iterate over it using 2 loops, perhaps even pack them into a nested list comprehension:

```
def do_math(row_idx, col_idx, value):

    if col_idx == 1:
       return (value + 2) * 5
    if row_idx == 3: 
        return value + 1
    return value

result = [
    [
        do_math(row_idx, col_idx, value)
        for col_idx, value in enumerate(row)
    ]
    for row_idx, row in enumerate(mtrx)
]

print(result)
```

Which gives the same result:

```
[[1, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 15, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 10, 1, 0, 1, 0], [2, 15, 1, 1, 2, 1], [1, 10, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 10, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: NLindros, your first solution is better for me that because i take some dynamic instruction in both row and column also map is faster then for loops in huge data like i used in my analyze.